# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list' when trying to split a text file

Tags: python, list, split

The program is intended to load a text file which has one proxy on each line. It then asks the user to input what separations they needed the proxies into. For example if I had 100 proxies in the text file on 100 separate lines, and said that I needed five 10 packs of proxies and two 25 packs of proxies, the program would output a total of seven text files which would add up to a total of 100 proxies.

```
filename = input('Enter a file name: ') 
    with open(filename) as f: ###load text file
        line_count = 0
        for line in f:
            line_count += 1 
    print("Number of proxies: " + str(line_count)) ###count proxies

pack10 = int(input("10 packs? ")) ###designate packs
pack25 = int(input("25 packs? "))
pack50 = int(input("50 packs? "))
pack100 = int(input("100 packs? "))
total = pack10*10 + pack25*25 + pack50*50 + pack100*100 ###calculate total proxies needed
packs = ([pack10]*10) + ([pack25]*25) + ([pack50]*50) + ([pack100]*100)

def split_list(filename, sizes): ###chunking of list
    with open(filename) as f:
        content = f.readlines()

    new_content = []
    start = 0
    for size in sizes:
        stop = start + size
        new_content.append(content[start:stop])
        start += size

    return new_content

splitted_list = split_list(filename, [packs])


if line_count < total:
    print("You need " + str((total - line_count)) + " more proxies") ###ensure right amount of proxies
else:
    for i, l in enumerate(splitted_list): ###chunk proxies
        with open('{}.txt'.format(i), 'w') as f:
            f.writelines(l) #output text files
            print("Complete")
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Username\Desktop\New Folder\proxies\splitter.py", line 28, in <module>
    splitted_list = split_list(filename, [packs])
  File "c:\Users\Username\Desktop\New Folder\proxies\splitter.py", line 22, in split_list
    stop = start + size
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Not sure what to do, the program works fine when I replace `[packs]` in `splitted_list = split_list(filename, [packs])` with `[5, 3, 2]` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `packs` is a two-dimensional list when you pass it to `split_list`.

When you define `packs` by adding `[pack10] * 10` up and so on, Python is taking liberties and creating a bunch of new lists with the pack variables simply appearing the number of times you multiply by.
              [image]

When you add these lists up together, it does the same thing again, creating one large one-dimensional list.
[image]

Then, as you're passing `packs` into `split_list`, you use square brackets, making `packs` a two-dimensional array.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the square brackets from this line:

```
splitted_list = split_list(filename, [packs])
```

so it becomes:

```
splitted_list = split_list(filename, packs)
```

Instead of passing in an array of sizes, you're wrapping your array in an extra layer of array, so the first element of sizes is actually what you want.
eg. Instead of passing in `[2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5]`, you're passing in `[[2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5]]`.